# Removing last comma from code?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, xampp

I am trying to remove the last comma so that it will look like

```
1,2,3 instead of 1,2,3,
```

Here is what I have so far;

```
<?php
    include_once 'header.php';
 ?>
<div id="content">
    Lesson on arrays<br />
    <?php
        $nums = array(0, 1, 2, 3);
        echo "My 1st array =";
        foreach ($nums as $value) {
        echo rtrim($value,",");
        }
?>
</div>
<?php
    include_once 'footer.php';
?>
```

Currently with the rtrim command in I am getting back

```
My 1st array =0123
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: When you iterate through your array, the `$value` doesn't actually contain a comma. If you would just have done an `echo $value;`, you would have gotten the same result as you are now. The comma is only to divide the values when you define the array, it doesn't actually gets saved as one.

Comment: So how should I solve my issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of for loop you can directly use `implode` function.

```
   <?php
       $nums = array(0, 1, 2, 3);
       echo "My 1st array =";
       echo implode(',',$nums);
  ?>
```

**Edit :** if you want foreach loop

```
<?php
         $nums = array(0, 1, 2, 3);
         echo "My 1st array =";
         $str='';
         foreach ($nums as $value) {
          $str.= $value.",";
         }
         echo rtrim($str,',');
 ?>
```

Comment: I realise impode may be easier however, I am required to use foreach

Comment: Is there any reason to use foreach

Comment: The lesson instructions my school provided requires it

Answer (score 2):

> Try this

```
$myStr = 'planes,trains,automobiles,';
$myStr = trim($myStr, ',');
```

**Output**

planes,trains,automobiles

Comment: As in add those two lines under foreach? I need to keep the foreach

Comment: Comma stays there

Comment: wait let me check

Answer (score 1):

Why to use foreach loop when you can do it without the loop, by using implode().
implode() function returns a string separated by  a "seperater" from the elements of an array.

```
$nums = array(0, 1, 2, 3); 

echo "My 1st array = "; 

$str=implode(",",$nums);

echo $str;
```

This will give you the output as
My 1st array = 0,1,2,3

Comment: It will gives error as implode function need two arguments

Answer (score 0):

If you must use that setup then use the $key in the foreach to determine if there should be a comma or not.

```
$nums = array(0, 1, 2, 3);
echo "My 1st array =";

foreach ($nums as $key => $value) {
    if($key !=0) echo ",";
    echo $value;
}
```

https://3v4l.org/kKKg1

Answer (score 0):

**You have two ways you can do with**

```html
<?php 
            $string = "";
            $nums = array(0, 1, 2, 3);
            echo "My 1st array = ";

            foreach ($nums as $value) {
                $string .= $value.",";
            }
            print_r(rtrim($string,','));
?>
```

**Or**

```html
<?php 

 $nums = array(0, 1, 2, 3);
 $string_by_implode = implode(',',$nums);
 echo "My 1st array = " . $string_by_implode;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use more generic way like following, here comma is attached from second element onwards:

`implode` is the quickest way to achieve this as explained in previous answer but if you are using `loop` then use below code:

```
<?php
$nums = array(0, 1, 2, 3);
echo "My 1st array =";

$comma = '';
foreach ($nums as $key => $value) {
    echo $comma . $value;
    $comma = ',';
}
?>
```